# RxJava: run a list of completables until one succeeds

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a function which takes a single input and returns a Completable.

I would like to run the function sequentially on a list of candidate inputs until I find one for which the Completable completes without an error.

```
fun doStuff(input: Int): Completable { ... }

Observable.just(1,2,3,4)
          .flatMapCompletable { doStuff(it) }
          .??? // Run completables until one succeeds
```

I'm not using `merge` or `concat` because they will execute all the Completables. I want it to stop executing the Completables once one has been found which succeeds.

Is there a standard operation for achieving this behavior?

Comment: Completable won't tell you if it completes with or without error unless you subscribe on it. What you can do is using `blockingGet()` and catch the exception until the Completable completes without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution, a little bit of RxAcrobatics is needed though:

```
Observable
    .just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .flatMapSingle { arg ->
        doStuff(arg)
            .toSingle { true }
            .onErrorReturn { false }
    }
    .filter { it }
    .firstElement()
    .subscribe()
```

If you have control over the function that returns the `Completable`, I suggest to change that into a `Single<Boolean>`, with that you could much more elegantly use `takeUntil` like this:

```
Observable
    .just(1,2, 3, 4)
    .flatMapSingle(::doStuff)
    .takeUntil { it }
    .subscribe()
```

If you don't have control over the function that returns the Completable, you might still create a small wrapper:

```
private fun doStuffWrap(foo: Int) = doStuff(foo)
    .toSingle { true }
    .onErrorReturn { false }
```

And use the elegant solution:

```
Observable
    .just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .flatMapSingle(::doStuffWrap)
    .takeUntil { it }
    .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `takeUntil` with your predicate checking if it succeeded or not.